# Unable to map an array of objects in a react accordion

Tags: reactjs, axios, mapping, accordion

I am fecting some data using axios and i am getting an array of objects which i want to map over an accordion.But i am unable to do so. How should i got about this? For accessing mainTitle i do sections.[0].mainTitle but in case of mapping what should be there?

```
"sections": [
      {
        "isLocked": false,
        "_id": "607ac29d24d10b74484c66e6",
        "mainTitle": "bcgjh",
        "description": "xnjgkh",
        "contents": [
          {
            "_id": "607ac29d24d10b74484c66e7",
            "typeOfContent": "document",
            "title": "SampleDoc.pdf",
            "description": "dfghj",
            "value": "https://schooleumetry.blob.core.windows.net/school/5599120788317986-SampleDoc.pdf"
          }
        ]
      },
 {
        "isLocked": false,
        "_id": "607ac29d24d10b74484c66e7",
        "mainTitle": "aaafadsh",
        "description": "xnjgndsfkh",
        "contents": [
          {
            "_id": "607ac29d24d10b74484c66e7",
            "typeOfContent": "document",
            "title": "SampleDoc1.pdf",
            "description": "dfghjadkfalkdf",
            "value": "https://schooleumetry.blob.core.windows.net/school/5599120788317986-SampleDoc1.pdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

````
{sections.map((l,index)=>
        <Card style={{paddingBottom:'30px',border:'none'}}>

            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={(l.number-1).toString()} >

                <h5 style={{position:'absolute',right:'20px'}}><HiOutlineChevronDown></HiOutlineChevronDown></h5>
                <h5><AiFillUnlock style={{paddingBottom:'5px',fontSize:'30px'}}/> Lesson no. {index+1}</h5>
            </Accordion.Toggle>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={l._id}>
                <Card.Body>
                       <h6>{l.mainTitle}</h6>
                       <h6>{l.descritpion}</h6>
                </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
    )}```
````

Comment: see this for map => https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-satoshi-lgdvb

Comment: how are you defining you sections constant?

Comment: @Tushar I am fetching this data from an api and storing it in a state. so here for instance sections is the state. And this is working sections has the data.

Comment: @Codenewbie  I am able to do this much but in the accordion it does'nt work probably because of my keys i guess i don't know really.

Comment: please could you attach any errors or warnings ...